# Passing string array to function and modifying it corrupts it

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a small programming language in C. I load a script from file and then tokenize it with strtok. The problem is that while in the tokenizer function the output is fine and gives me the expected results, but when the function returns to main the data is corrupted, giving me output like:

```
╠ a
```

Instead of the expected:

```
int
```

I don't have a ton of experience in C but my best guess is that this is a null termination issue, although I've read that strtok should automatically do that.

Below is the relevant code:

```
int tokenize(char* script, char* tokens[]) {
    char buffer[256];
    strcpy(buffer, script);

    char* token = strtok(buffer, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while (token) {
        tokens[i] = token;
        printf("token: %s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    printf("First token (tokenize): %s\n", tokens[0]);

    return i;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // ....
    char* script = read_script(argv[1]);

    char* tokens[256];
    int token_count = tokenize(script, tokens);
    printf("First token (main): %s\n", tokens[0]);
    // ...
}
```

And here is the console output:

```
token: int
token: i
token: =
token: 0

First token (tokenize): int
First token (main): ╠ a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning pointers that point to tokens in a local variable:

```
int tokenize(char* script, char* tokens[]) {
    char buffer[256];
    ...
```

`buffer` no longer exists once `tokenize()` returns.

Comment: And the question that would have probably let the OP figure this out for themself is this one: Who or what allocated the space these pointers point to and who or what is responsible for deallocating them?

Answer (score 1):

Your `strtok`-calls operate on local variable `buffer[256]`, and the memory reserved for this variable is no longer valid once `tokenize` returns. Hence, any pointer in `tokens[]` will point to (invalid) memory.

To overcome this, I'd write

```
    tokens[i] = strdup(token);
```

intstead of

```
    tokens[i] = token;
```

Make sure that the caller frees the memory thereby reserved for each `token[i]` element, once these elements are not needed any more.

Answer (score 0):

Memory space(buffer) that pointed by tokens is located in stack. So, that space is disapeared when "tokenize"function is end.
So, you "tokens" variable must pointing heap area.(by using malloc or calloc.)